# Do getters and setters only work with primitive values in ES5?

Tags: javascript

Do getters and setters only work with primitive values in ES5?

```
var foo = { 
  get bar() {
    return this._bar;
  },
  set bar(value) {
    this._bar = value;
  } 
}

foo.bar = function() {}; //appears to overwrite the property rather than assign the value of _bar
```

Comment: In the project I'm currently working on, we are using them with classes that we created.

Comment: Classes as in ES6 classes?

Comment: We are using typescript with ES5 transpiler

Comment: "*appears to overwrite the property*" - why do you think so? It doesn't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes you think that it overwrites the property?

```
var foo = { 
  get bar() {
    console.log('the getter is still here');
    return this._bar;
  },
  set bar(value) {
    this._bar = value;
  } 
}

foo.bar = function() { console.log('xxx'); };
```

When running `foo.bar()` the output is:

> the getter is still here
>   xxx